# ASP.NET custom RoleProvider - use of cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

At present on login I am inserting a row for the user into an AccessSession table that keeps details of what roles the user has along with the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.

My custom implementation of the GetRolesForUser method of this is:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();
        string[] rolesArray;
        char[] splitter = { '|' };            

        string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value;
        AccessSession sessionObject = AccessSession.Get(sessionId);

        if (sessionObject != null)
        {
            rolesArray = sessionObject.Roles.Split(splitter);

            foreach (string role in rolesArray)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
                {
                    roles.Add(role);
                }
            }
        }
        return roles.ToArray();
    }
```

The question I have is am I wrong using this approach?  If cookies are disabled then there will be no HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].  My alternative plan was to insert an AccessSession object in to Session but this always appears null when the custom RoleProvider tried to access it.

I could use cacheRolesInCookie=true but again that would be no better than the above approach as disabling cookies would break the functionality.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it in the end by getting the roles from the FormsAuthenticationTicket which held all my roles in already.  Here is an example of the code:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();
        string[] rolesArray = new string[] { };
        char splitter = Advancedcheck.BLL.Common.Const.default_splitter;

        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                {
                    FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                    rolesArray = ticket.UserData.Split(splitter);

                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, rolesArray);
                }
            }
        }

        if (rolesArray.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string role in rolesArray)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
                {
                    roles.Add(role.ToLower());
                }
            }
        }
        return roles.ToArray();
    }
```